# mvc .net and jquery applying it on a dynamic set of links

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

so i have a dynamically generated set of links:

```
<a class="link"href="linkto/1" id="1">link 1</a>
<a class="link"href="linkto/2" id="2">link 2</a>
<a class="link"href="linkto/3" id="3">link 3</a>
```

and then these links calls an action that returns a list of data and populates a div (which is also dynamically generated right under the link)

```
<a class="link" href="linkto/1" id="1">link 1</a>
<div class="container" id="1"></div>
<a class="link" href="linkto/2" id="2">link 2</a>
<div class="container" id="2"></div>
<a class="link" href="linkto/3" id="3">link 3</a>
<div class="container" id="3"></div>
```

this is my jquery

```
var url;
        var id;
        $('a.link').click(function () {
            url= $(this).attr('href');
            id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (data) {
                    var list = '';
                    var listcontainer = $('div.container').attr({ id: id.toString() });
                    $.each(data, function (i, client) {
                        list += '<div class="' + client.Id + '">Name of client = ' + client.Name + '</div>';
                    });
                    $(listcontainer).addClass("box-list-small");
                    $(listcontainer).html(list);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('Cant load client list.');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

so what I'm trying to achieve is that there would be a link and when it gets clicked a box under it opens up to show the list. the problem is, everytime i click the link of one, it populates ever "container" in the page. Does that make sense?

Appreciate the time!

Thanks!!

EDIT: modified pseudo code.

```
<div class="row">
    <a class="link" href="linkto/1" id="1">link 1</a>
    <a class="someotherlink">someotherlink</a>
  </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="container" id="1"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <a class="link" href="linkto/2" id="2">link 2</a>
    <a class="someotherlink">someotherlink</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="container" id="2"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <a class="link" href="linkto/3" id="3">link 3</a>
    <a class="someotherlink">someotherlink</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="container" id="3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line: `var listcontainer = $('div.container').attr({ id: id.toString() });`
queries the DOM for *every* div with class "container", then sets all of their ids to the clicked link's id.. and returns the collection of divs into listcontainer variable. Then you call `.html(list)` on it so it sets all the containers.

You probably want something more like this:

```
$('a.link').click(function () {
        var el = $(this),
            url= el.attr('href'),
            id = el.attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                var list = '';
                $.each(data, function (i, client) {
                    list += '<div class="' + client.Id + '">Name of client = ' + client.Name + '</div>';
                });
                el.next('.container').addClass("box-list-small").html(list);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Cant load client list.');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: it can't seem to find the "el.next". it gets the proper attr values tho. it's just not showing up..

Comment: the `el.next('.container')` is based on the HTML you pasted (the 2nd snippet). if your DOM structure is different then you'd need something else.. (`el.next('.container')` looks for an element immediately following the clicked element)

Comment: so my divs are kind of convoluted cuz of the links. i updated the original post to include all the divs. was trying diff stuffs like el.nextAll and el.closest. but on the console it'll log like this [object Object]

Comment: according to your updated html, you'd need `el.closest('.row').next('.row').find('.container')`